# TableView ReparatorInset Width - Swift 4 Without Storyboard

Tags: ios, ios4

I'm trying to design an app with the width of the separatorInset being short. I can achieve that but the label in the cell gets short also.

```
tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 205, bottom: 0, right: 10)
```

Is it possble to target the actual `separatorInset` only and not to width of the row? The label should not be affected. I only need to shorten the `separator`.

Result expected:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use custom cells and to have a UIView with 1px height as separator.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I was seconds away from doing just that. That should be easily done.